# Issue uploading files

Tags: assets, upload, permissions

I have completed a website for a school who can't upload files when in school.
When they upload a file the status bar loads the full way across the screen but at the top right it just keeps spinning. Nothing more happens - the files doesn't become available.
I can upload fine from home and the staff can upload fine at home as well.
What is the likely cause of this issue - I have log files to check if need be - I deleted the log files then asked them to try and upload a file - then I took a copy of the log files with Dev Mode on.

Is this likely to be a Firewall Issue in the school? I did a website for another local school who would have the same IT provider but have no issues there.

Comment: the log files would be a good place to start. Writing Permission seems a probable cause. It could also be that the files they try to upload exceeds the max upload limit or the file is corrupted.

Comment: I can upload files no problem here. The files they have tried to upload have worked ok when they have taken them home so I assume permissions is ok and the files they are uploading are ok.

Comment: Checking `craft/storage/runtime/logs` for upload related errors as well as your web server's error logs is a good place to start.  I'd also recommend checking the response for the upload request in your browser's console.  If you're not getting a response body, then the response status code is a good clue to start with.

Comment: I know this is a super old post, but I'm having the same exact issue with an installation of craft that I'm working on. Were you able to resolve this issue? Oddly enough, whenever I open the network tab and refresh to see the responses, everything uploads as expected.

Comment: In my case it was an issue with the school. I asked them to report the issue to their IT Provider so must have been something on their firewall blocking it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm glad you identified and resolved the issue!

I stumbled across this post because I had the same GUI response/result in Craft CMS and want to share how I resolved it for others that may have the same issue without being a firewall problem.

[See my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55767091/9640213)